# JPA: Many To one delete on cascade doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

In my app try to delete on cascade but doesn't work, I am using JpaResposiory

On my class user, I don't have any reference to Incidence

JPA REPOSITORY for Incidence

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "incidence")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Incidence {
...
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE},optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user; 

}
```

JPA REPOSITORY for Incidence

```java
package cat.copernic.backend.data.models.incidence;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface IncidenceRepository extends JpaRepository<Incidence,Integer>{

    
}
```

JPA REPOSITORY for User

```java
package cat.copernic.backend.data.models.user;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer>{
    
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

    Optional<User> findByNif(String nif);

}
```

Service that implement repository

```java
package cat.copernic.backend.data.models.incidence;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class IncidenceServiceImpl implements IncidenceService {

    @Autowired
    private IncidenceRepository incidenceRepository;

    @Override
    public void save(Incidence incidence) {
        incidenceRepository.save(incidence);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Incidence> getAll() {
        return incidenceRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Incidence getById(Integer id) {
        return incidenceRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Incidence incidence) {
        save(incidence);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        incidenceRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

I try to put the delete method on transaccional and put on cascasde all but doesn't work

Comment: show please the code in interface , extend JpaRespository